# How correctly write a file received from Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to make a simple web API for receiving a file from server.

Here's the server part:

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
var stream = new FileStream(itemPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
      new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
      new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = itemPath };
return result;
```

The client part:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var responce = Task.Run(() => client.GetAsync(@"https://localhost:...")).Result;
var bytes = Task.Run(() => responce.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()).Result;
var writer = 
  new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write));
writer.Write(bytes);
writer.Close();
```

And the written file content:

```
{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,
"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Type","value":["application/octet-stream"]},{"key":"Content-Disposition",
"value":["attachment; filename=\"=?utf-8?B?ZDpcTGlicmFyeVBhdGhc0J/QsNGH0LXQutC+XEV4YW1wbGUgR
DVcQ2QxN1xDTElQQlJEXE1haW5Gcm0ucGFz?=\""]}]},"statusCode":200,
"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

I expected this file will contain a file from server itself, but not JSON describing it.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The content of the response should not be what appears to be a JSON representation of a `HttpResponseMessage`.

Asp.net Core Web API is reading the `HttpResponseMessage` class like a normal model object and serializing it to JSON.

Refactor the server side code to use the suggested syntax in the controller

```
public IActionResult MyAction(...) {
    //...
    var stream = new FileStream(itemPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", "desired file name here");
}
```

which returns a `IActionResult` derived `FileStreamResult`

On the client side, try avoiding blocking calls like `.Result`. It is also unclear why async calls are being wrapped in `Task.Run` when they can already be awaited.

Keep the code async all the way through

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(@"https://localhost:..."); ;
var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
var fileName = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write)) {
    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

The response content could have been read as a stream and copied directly over to the file stream

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(@"https://localhost:..."); ;
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var fileName = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write)) {
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: @Nikosi, yes, with `IActionResult ` it works correctly. About the client part - I tried `await` first, but in this case execution continues without waiting and breakpoint on the line `var bytes = await response...` is never reached. I didn't think about it yet (maybe, it will be my next question :). Thank you!